# Sheaves and gratings

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory

A *grating* is a notion in algebraic topology from the 1940 introduced by Alexander. Cartan extended it as follows.

A grating (carapace in french) is defined by a topological space $X$, a module (or a differential ring) $A$ and for each $x \in X$, a surjective morphism $\varphi_x$ from $A$ to some quotient $A_x$ such that

- for all $\alpha \in A$ and $x \in X$ such that $\varphi_x(\alpha) = 0$, we have $\varphi_y(\alpha) = 0$ for all $y$ close to $x$.
- If $\varphi_x(\alpha) = 0$ for all $x\in X$, then $\alpha = 0$.

In his seminar [Carapaces](http://www.numdam.org/item/SHC_1950-1951__3__A18_0/) from the 1950, Cartan showed that gratings correspond to (pre-)sheaves on $X$ and this is the reason why, I guess, the notion of grating is not used anymore.

The sheaf $\mathcal F$ associated to a grating $(A, \varphi_x)$ is built by taking the $A_x$ as the stalks. This, I understand. The grating associated to a sheaf is built from the module of sections. Cartan does not give any other details in the [seminar](http://www.numdam.org/item/SHC_1950-1951__3__A18_0/). I don't understand what $A$ should be, hence my question:

> What is the module $A$ associated to the sheaf $\mathcal F$?

The module $A_x$ must be the stalk of the sheaf. So $A$ can't be the module of global sections, since it does not always surject on the stalks. My guess would be something like the inverse limit of all the ${\mathcal F}(U)$, where $U$ is an arbitrary open subset of $X$. But I have never seen this limit used before in that context.

Comment: Why not product of $F(U)$ over all $U$?

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet What would be the projection ${\cal F}(U) \mapsto {\cal F}_x$? Also I don't think that point 1 would hold.

Comment: Is 'grating' really the standard translation?  [Google](https://translate.google.com/?sl=fr&tl=en&text=carapace&op=translate) thinks, with no context, that 'carapace' means 'shell', so it seems like 'shelling' might make more sense.

Comment: Yes, this is the translation used by Cartan. Grating is the term used by Alexander in his 1938 paper and Cartan used the same term in his 1949 course for a slightly more general concept. The definition of carapace given in the linked seminar matches the definition of a grating given in his course.

Comment: If you take the subset of the product consistued of "coherent sections" then property 1 seems to work no? The projection is the obvious one if $x \in U$ and 0 else.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Yes, but then I guess this construction gives the module of global sections. Which probably is what Cartan had in mind.

Comment: I think he says global sections is what he has in mind: (copy and pasted with minor editing) "Inversement~ tout faisceau $F$ définit une carapace, à savoir le module
des sections $\Gamma(F)$ . En effet, dans l’exposé 14 (numéro 1) on a défini des supports dans $\Gamma(F)$ ; et on vérifie aussitôt que les axiomes d’une carapace sont remplis. Pour tout faisceau $F$ et toute famille $\Phi$, $\Gamma_{\Phi}(F)$  est carapace."

Comment: @SimonWadsley Yes, I must have read too much in the paper. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have misunderstood what Cartan was doing. In modern language he defined functors $\Gamma$ from sheaves to gratings and $\mathcal{F}$ from gratings to sheaves but he did not claim that these are mutually inverse equivalences of categories (even allowing for the apparent anachronism). He did write down a natural transformation from the identity functor on gratings to the functor $\Gamma \circ F$ explained at the end of section 4 of the seminar you link to.

He called objects $A$ where the map $A\to \Gamma\circ F(A)$ is an isomorphism *complete gratings* and argues that $\Gamma$ of any sheaf is a complete grating. I guess we should understand this as meaning that $\Gamma$ is right adjoint to $F$ but I haven't worked through the details to check this is true.

To directly answer your specific question, I think the module $A$ underlying $\Gamma(\mathcal{F})$ is in fact the space of global sections $\mathcal{F}(X)$ and your argument that it cannot be so fails since we don't have $A_x=\mathcal{F}_x$ in general. Rather, I think if you work through Cartan's argument, $A_x$ can be defined to be the image of $\mathcal{F}(X)$ in $\mathcal{F}_x$.

Comment: One thing this has made me curious about: if the natural transformation $\mathrm{id}\to \Gamma\circ F$ is indeed the unit of an adjunction defined by $\Gamma$ and $F$ then what is the meaning of the counit and does it naturally arise in the theory of sheaves?